# VB.NET -> C# Syntax problems

Tags: c#, vb.net, adox

I want to create a new MS Access database table using ADOX. On [this page](http://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_database/microsoftaccess/article.php/c5149/), is code in VB.NET, but obviously it's not working in C# (when I want to "convert" the code). I'll be grateful if someone converts it correctly.

---

In VB.NET is:

```
     Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection, Cat As ADOX.Catalog, _
                        objTable As ADOX.Table
```

but, in C#, there's no ADODB.Connection method

here's my code, I don't really think it's OK:

```
        string ConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/TempDB.mdb") + ";";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr);

        ADOX.Catalog Cat = new ADOX.Catalog();
        ADOX.Table objTable = new ADOX.Table();
        conn.Open();

        Cat.ActiveConnection = conn; //Here is the error message "Specified cast is not valid."

        objTable.Name = "Table2";

        objTable.Columns.Append("ID", DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, 100);

        objTable.Keys.Append("PrimaryKey", KeyTypeEnum.adKeyPrimary, "ID", "Table1", "IDColumn");

        Cat.Tables.Append(objTable);
```

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble converting to C# ?

Comment: Show us your efforts, and we will help you with the parts that do not work.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to add a reference to the ADOX assembly in your project.  Once you've done that, the C# code would look like this:

```
using System;
using ADOX;

namespace ConsoleProgram1
{
    public class ConsoleProgram1
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

              Catalog cat = new Catalog();

              cat.Create("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                 "Data Source=D:\AccessDB\NewMDB.mdb;" & _
                 "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5");

              Console.WriteLine("Database Created Successfully")

        }

    }
}
```

Although my exposure to ADOX is limited to this question, the code snippets I saw at your link aren't encouraging.  Things like the `cat = Nothing` line demonstrates a misunderstanding of how .Net changed things when from VB6.  Hopefully that doesn't extend to the library.

Comment: The `cat = Nothing` wasn't necessary in the original VB6 either.

Comment: +1 The suggestion to use cat.Create to avoid using an ADODB.Connection is inspired.